# What is foundry-specific IP?

Tags: fpga

I just read the following [article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1332241) but didn't understand what they meant by foundry-specific.

Comment: The article is for clarification and/or context. The question is specific. You don't have to read the article to answer the question if you know the answer.

Comment: would it help to quote `The TSMC IP Alliance Program, a component[...]` paragraph in your question to provide some additional context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means specific to that Foundry and also specific to their IC manufacturing process.

You can buy IP at ARM, make a design with it and have a Foundry make your chips. You'd be using non-foundry specific IP since it is ARM and your IP. You can go to any Foundry to have your chips fabricated.

But perhaps you need a ROM or RAM to go with your design. Usually you would not use a generic ROM or RAM design as you want your ROM or RAM to have the smallest size possible so ROM or RAM are very **process specific** IPs. They're provided / generated by the Foundry.

You could not use that ROM or RAM design on a different process or different Foundry as that IP is specific for one process only.

Answer (score 4):

It just means, IP (partial designs) that is only meant to work when implemented in a process from a particular foundry.

For example I might offer an IP block (an Ethernet MAC design, or an 8-bit microprocessor design, or as in the article, a design for a block of configurable logic) that is designed specifically to work on a TSMC process (as in the article) or in a Global Foundries process, or wherever.

The alternative would be to offer a design that could work on multiple processes from different foundries. The advantage of making foundry-specific IP is that the designer only needs to verify its function and performance on one process, and the designer can take advantage of specific gate designs or other blocks offered by that foundry to optimize the design.